# check next node xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I am stuck with my code I need to transform this simple html

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<p>
    <img src="xxxxx" />
</p>
<div class="sourceimg">azerrty</div>
<p>
    <img src="xxxxx">
</p>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<p>
    <img src="xxxxx">
</p>
<div class="sourceimg">qwerty</div>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
```

to

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<figure>
    <img src="xxxxx" />
    <figcaption>
        <cite>
            azerrty
        </cite>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<figure>
    <img src="xxxxx">
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="xxxxx">
    <figcaption>
        <cite>
            qwerty
        </cite>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
```

I manage to wrap img with figure tag but I don't know how can I check the next node ( `<div class="sourceimg"> xxx </div>` ) if It is exist or not

this is what I did :

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$html = <<<EOF
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<p>
    <img src="xxxxx" />
</p>
<div class="sourceimg">azerrty</div>
<p>
    <img src="xxxxx">
</p>
<div class="sourceimg">azerrty</div>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<p>
    <img src="xxxxx">
</p>
<div class="sourceimg">qwerty</div>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
EOF;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$matches = $xpath->query('//p//img');

if($matches->length > 0){
    foreach($matches as $node){

        $figure_node = $dom->createElement('figure');

        $node->parentNode->replaceChild($figure_node, $node);
        $figure_node->appendChild($node);


    }
}

$contenu = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $contenu;

?>
```

and the output :

```
<p>
    <figure><img src="xxxxx">
    </figure>
</p>
<div class="sourceimg">azerrty</div>
<p>
    <figure><img src="xxxxx">
    </figure>
</p>
<div class="sourceimg">azerrty</div>
<p>
    <figure><img src="xxxxx">
    </figure>
</p>
<div class="sourceimg">qwerty</div>
```

Comment: can you show us your current output?

Comment: I have edited my post with the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED CODE] I will do the following:

```
...
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$matches = $xpath->query('//p//img');
$matchesDivs = $xpath->query('//div');

if($matches->length > 0 && $matchesDivs->length > 0){
    $divSeen = [];
    $step = -1;
    foreach($matches as $node){
         if($node->getElementsByTagName('img')->length == 0){
             continue;
         }             
         $step++;
         $figure_node = $dom->createElement('figure');
         $figure_node->appendChild($node->getElementsByTagName('img')[0]);
         $node->parentNode->replaceChild($figure_node, $node);

         if(!in_array($matchesDivs[$step]->nodeValue, $divSeen)){
            $figCaption_node = $dom->createElement('figcaption');
            $cite_node = $dom->createElement('cit',$matchesDivs[$step]->nodeValue);

            $figCaption_node->appendChild($cite_node);
            $figure_node->appendChild($figCaption_node);
            $divSeen[]=$matchesDivs[$step]->nodeValue;
         }
         $matchesDiv[$step]->parentNode->removeChild($matchesDiv[$step]);
    }
}

$contenu = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $contenu;

?>
```

check it here: [eval.in](https://eval.in/799124)

Output:

```
<p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<figure><img src="xxxxx"><figcaption><cit>azerrty</cit></figcaption></figure>

<figure><img src="xxxxx"></figure>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<figure><img src="xxxxx"><figcaption><cit>qwerty</cit></figcaption></figure>
```

Comment: your are checking if the sourceimg Value is in array but in my html I can i same the sourceimg so I need to keep it and sometimes I have no sourceimg

Comment: then update your example and i'm not checking the `sourceimg` at all, just the `div`. As you see the result is exact what you expect (only the `Lorem ipsum` p tags are different, because in the example I inserted them at different places)

Comment: oh ok, but you know if you update all the time your requirements is like I'm doing the work for you. So you should research your question and then not change it. You can edit it to be clearer, but not to add new features or so. You can also work from the given state and evolve/develop it to what you need.